# Division of rows based on date in long format

Tags: r, dataframe, division

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Datum = as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2015-02-02","2015-03-03","2015-04-04","2015-05-05",
                                    "2015-02-02","2015-04-04","2015-01-01","2015-03-03","2015-05-05")), 
                  Par = c(rep("N",5),rep("P",5)), val = 10:1)

        Datum Par val
1  2015-01-01   N  10
2  2015-02-02   N   9
3  2015-03-03   N   8
4  2015-04-04   N   7
5  2015-05-05   N   6
6  2015-02-02   P   5
7  2015-04-04   P   4
8  2015-01-01   P   3
9  2015-03-03   P   2
10 2015-05-05   P   1
```

I want to do a division of the rows with par = N by the rows with par = P on the same date, and add this to the dataframe. The expected result should be:

```
        Datum Par       val
1  2015-01-01   N 10.000000
2  2015-02-02   N  9.000000
3  2015-03-03   N  8.000000
4  2015-04-04   N  7.000000
5  2015-05-05   N  6.000000
6  2015-02-02   P  5.000000
7  2015-04-04   P  4.000000
8  2015-01-01   P  3.000000
9  2015-03-03   P  2.000000
10 2015-05-05   P  1.000000
11 2015-01-01 N/P  3.333333
12 2015-02-02 N/P  1.800000
13 2015-03-03 N/P  4.000000
14 2015-04-04 N/P  1.750000
15 2015-05-05 N/P  6.000000
```

I know i can convert to wide format (e.g. `dcast` from `reshape2`), then sum the columns, and paste them under the original df1, but that seems a bit complicated.
So my question is, can this be done in long format?

Comment: what you described is not what you wrote as output. Here is a way to stick to what you described: `rbind(df1, data.frame(Par='N/P',val=with(df1, val[Par=='N']/val[Par=='P'])))`

Comment: exactly same code ^^

Comment: @akrun, I realize that my minimal example was a to minimal. I need to add a date, complicating things a bit. and BTW: I think i did divide N by P, 10/5 = 2 and 6 / 1 = 6 or am i wrong?

Comment: @RHA you can update your question regarding the dates. And it's not us to decide to divide which quantity by which quantity, you should konw what you exactly want to achieve ;)

Comment: @RHA It is your first dataframe that contains wrong values. The first part (up to line 10) of the second one is consistent with your desired output, but these ten lines are different from those in `df1` displayed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the edited dataset, we can `rbind` the original dataset with the dataset we created from the ratio of 'val' with other columns grouped by 'Datum'.

Here, I am using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`). Grouped by 'Datum' (`by = .(Datum)`), we get the ratio of 'val' for corresponding 'N', 'P' elements in 'Par'.  As there are missing dates or dates with only a single value, we leave that row as such by a condition (`if(.N>1)`) ie. if the number of rows in that .Datum group is greater than 1, we do the ratio calculation and create 'N/P' as the 'Par' column.  After this is done, we can `rbind` with the original dataset.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1) 
 rbind(df1,df1[, if(.N>1) list(Par='N/P', 
           val=val[Par=='N']/val[Par=='P'] ), .(Datum)])
#         Datum Par       val
# 1: 2015-01-01   N 10.000000
# 2: 2015-02-02   N  9.000000
# 3: 2015-03-03   N  8.000000
# 4: 2015-04-04   N  7.000000
# 5: 2015-05-05   N  6.000000
# 6: 2015-02-02   P  5.000000
# 7: 2015-04-04   P  4.000000
# 8: 2015-01-01   P  3.000000
# 9: 2015-03-03   P  2.000000
#10: 2015-05-05   P  1.000000
#11: 2015-01-01 N/P  3.333333
#12: 2015-02-02 N/P  1.800000
#13: 2015-03-03 N/P  4.000000
#14: 2015-04-04 N/P  1.750000
#15: 2015-05-05 N/P  6.000000
```

Comment: A nice solution, that even takes care of possible missing values. Thanks! @akrun you may want to remove the old comments above.